# How to change the projection of a map (created from ETOPO1 bathymetry data) in R

Tags: r, maps, r-raster, map-projections

I have downloaded a TIF file from the ETOPO1 website, which contains bathymetry information.  I have plotted the bathymetry map using the following code:

```
bathy <- raster("ice_data.tif")

plot(bathy)

bathy[bathy>0] <-0

dev.new()

plot(bathy)

intervals<-c(-0.000001, -500, -1000, -5000)

colourscale<-colorRampPalette(c("blue","lightblue1"))
plot(bathy, breaks=intervals, col = colourscale(4))
```

I am wanting to change the project of the map (to this: `+proj=laea +lon_0=-21.09375 +lat_0=-90 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`).  I have tried using the code below (with `st_transform()` function), but am getting an error message

`Error in UseMethod("st_transform") :  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')`

```
new_map = st_transform(bathy, crs = "+proj=laea +lon_0=-21.09375 +lat_0=-90 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?  It would be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For rasters you need to use the `raster::crs()` function to change the crs.

The `sf::st_transform()` function needs an sf object as input.

Try:

```
new_crs <- "+proj=laea +lon_0=-21.09375 +lat_0=-90 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

crs(bathy) <- new_crs
```